# Настроить авторизацию?

Tags: битрикс, авторизация

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в Битриксе настроить авторизацию таким образом, чтобы при открытии сайта появлялась форма авторизации и без авторизации дальше не пускала.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще никаких проблем: вам надо в настройках доступа главной страницы указать ограничения для какой-то группы.

"Права на доступ к разделу" / 
"Доступ по умолчанию для всех пользователей": "Доступ закрыт"

А открыть для какой-то конкретной группы.